# In Org Mode Autocomplete, is it Possible to show possible values of Header Arguments

Tags: org-mode

Editing an Org file code block, one can type #+ which offers autocomplete options including BEGIN_SRC - good so far. Typing a space, autocomplete offers (only) allowed language completions, including python - still good. Typing :, :results is offered as one option (although it seems there is a minor bug that gets ::results). So one may have

## +BEGIN_SRC python :results

## +END_SRC

Is there a way for autocomplete to offer allowed results values, listed here?

http://orgmode.org/manual/results.html#results

(collection, type, format, handling)